# Is there machine learning for image classification in ArcGIS 10.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-pro, image-classification

I have access to ArcGIS 10.3. Do I need to get ArcGIS Pro to have access to machine learning?
I've read that this is a built-in function in ArcGIS Pro.
links:
http://www.esri.com/esri-news/arcuser/spring-2018/machine-learning-in-arcgis
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=duZ7jor_YrU

Comment: Where did you read this?  Please include links to research that you have done prior to asking questions so that potential answerers can more quickly find references to information that you mention.

Answer (score 2):

Machine learning is a broad term that includes several algorithms. More and more of these algorithms are available in ArcGIS IF YOU HAVE the **spatial analyst** or the **image analyst** extension.

Here are the main novelties. As far as I know they are available from ArcMap (no need of ArcGIS Pro).

Since ArcGIS 9.2, you have a multivariate toolset that include a supervised (**Maximum likelihood**) and an unsupervised (**isoCluster**) classifier.

You then have to wait for ArcGIS 10.3 to have **support vector machine classifier**, and 10.4 for a **random forest** classifier.

And with ArcGIS 10.6 you have support for some **deep learning** classifiers (you can convert a model from Tenserflow or microsoft CNTK into a classifier running with ArcGIS.